# QMediaPlayer крашит код

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

Qt 6.4.2

При работе с QMediaPlayer или QAudioOutput приложение при запуске крашится к сообщением "Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)"

Из-за чего происходит ошибка и как этого избежать?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>
#include <QtMultimedia/QAudioOutput>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget(nullptr);
    auto player  = new QMediaPlayer(&widget);
    auto audioOutput  = new QAudioOutput(&widget);
    player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("..//Oxy.mp3"));
    audioOutput->setVolume(50);
    player->play ();
    widget.resize(200, 100);
    widget.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Comment: вместо скриншота отправь код! (без негатива)

Comment: вместо скриншота отправь код! (с негативом) А вообще, эта ошибка говорит о том, что исполняемый файл не может найти все нужные dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось, что вся проблема в том, что CLion не мог найти bin Qt и вообще работать с шестой его версией
После того, как я загуглил ошибку, посоветовали в настройках проекта выставить путь к bin Qt, после чего мне стало выдавать ошибку:

> could not load multimedia backend ""
> QtMultimedia is not currently supported on this platform or compiler.

Так что я перенёс весь код в чистый проект Qt и данный код стал работать.
main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QUrl>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget(nullptr);
    auto *player  = new QMediaPlayer(&widget);
    auto *audioOutput  = new QAudioOutput(&widget);
    player->setAudioOutput(audioOutput);
    player->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("..//Audio1//Oxy.mp3"));
    audioOutput->setVolume(100);
    player->play ();
    widget.resize(200, 100);
    widget.show();
    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Audio1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS
        Core
        Gui
        Widgets
        Multimedia
        REQUIRED)

add_executable(Audio1 main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Audio1
        Qt::Core
        Qt::Gui
        Qt::Widgets
        Qt::Multimedia
        )


install(TARGETS Audio1
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

Надеюсь, кому-нибудь помог, если что, поправляйте.

Answer (score 0):

инклюды вида `#include <QtMultimedia/QMediaPlayer>` намекают что QtMultimedia не подключена.

Для qmake в .pro файле это будет строчка типа

> QT += multimedia

А для cmake вроде как что-то типа (но это не точно)

> find_package(Qt5Multimedia REQUIRED)

И инклюды у вас будут без путей `#include <QMediaPlayer>`

Comment: Multimedia было подключено, но без подобного вызова библиотеки не обнаруживались. 
Оказалось, что проблема с bin файлами и работы Qt6 совместно с CLion (сейчас, понимаю, что конфигурацию стоило упомянуть)